# Can't display InfoWindow on Google Maps V3 (map is not defined)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm experimenting with de API google maps, i tried to display an infowindow when I clicking the marker, but display in devtools this:

***main.js:56 Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined(…)***

I found that my addlistener should be in on the **function geocodeaddress** but it still no show :(
This is my code:

```
 function initMap() {
        // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
         var  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.1528213,-101.7136297);
          var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapa");
          var OpcionesMapa = {center: latlng, zoom: 12};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, OpcionesMapa);

         // marcador.setMap(map);
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

         document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(){
          geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
         });



        }

  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var pinColor = "01A9DB"; //Blue
var pinImage = new        google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor, 
    new google.maps.Size(21, 34), 
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

   var address = document.getElementById('domicilio').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: pinImage

      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Hello'

});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });


    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The error I get with the posted code is  `Uncaught ReferenceError: pinImage is not defined(…)`

Comment: Sorry I forgot put  the code from MarkerImage

Comment: A [mcve] doesn't require `pinImage`, the error implies that you didn't test the code that you posted for us.  Note also, the `MarkerImage` class has been deprecated for a fairly long time now, replaced by the `Icon` anonymous object definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined(…)` inside the function `geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap)` because inside that function, `map` is undefined.  The name of the `google.maps.Map` object inside that routine is `resultsMap`.

```
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: resultsMap,
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    // icon: pinImage

  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
  });
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.1528213, -101.7136297);
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("mapa");
  var OpcionesMapa = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 12
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, OpcionesMapa);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {

  var address = document.getElementById('domicilio').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
      });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Hello'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
      });

    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapa {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="domicilio" value="Leon, Guanajuato" />
<input id="submit" type="button" value="submit" />
<div id="mapa"></div>
```

**

Comment: Thank youu so muchhh!